# How to show modalInput div using js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" class="modalInput glow" rel="#newsletter" >Newsletter!</a>
```

This opens a modal window, contents held in the #newsletter div.
Since I have not located code for this inside the source of the page, I assume this is an inbuilt functionality of jQuery, and I am not familiar with it.

I want to open the same modal window by code. What code do I have to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the [simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) by Eric Martin.

I'm not aware of such functionality pre-built into JQuery, but with simple-modal it's extremely easy to pop a modal window. Just run something like this:

```
   $("#sample").modal();
```

This would show a modal with the contents of the #sample div.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is the only dialog I am aware of that you can get from jQuery UI widgets.